# Why is the immersed image of the Klein bottle $S^2$ with three closed discs identified?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, klein-bottle

Someone said that there are three discs glued together on the Klein bottle self-intersecting itself in a circle. Here is a picture:

[image]

They said that one from the "near" side of the tiny connecting tube, one is in the middle (the one that is blocking the tube), and one is on the far side of the tube.

This description makes no sense to me at all whatsoever, even referring to the picture I have no idea what "near" or "far" means, or what "connecting tube" or "blocking the tube" means, etc.

They also said if I take the common disc out and shorten the tube away from the intersection then glue back the three discs, I would get a $2-$sphere. But I don't know what "common disc" means (or what the three discs are).

Maybe someone could show pictures or mark the diagram with what is going on? Thank you

Comment: If you 'cut' along the disc of self-intersection you get something homeomorphic to a 2-sphere: see [here](http://i.imgur.com/P83itP9.png). Now if you glue those two black discs together along the green disc (which is where they used to intersect), you recover the first picture.

Comment: @MikeMiller I see that now, but why did this other person say three discs are required to glue back on in order to obtain the $2-$sphere? It looks like you only need two.

Comment: I don't understand what your friend is talking about, and since he's not here, I can't ask him to clarify. Here's how I might interpret it: the image of the above immersion (i.e., the picture you've drawn here) is homeomorphic to what you get when you take three disjoint discs on $S^2$ and glue them together in a certain manner. The three discs here are the two black discs and the original green disc.